# what does "such as" refer to in this quote?

Tags: meaning

This is a quote from Kant.

> I do not wish to hide the fact that I can only look with repugnance .. upon the puffed-up pretentiousness of all these volumes filled with wisdom, **such as are fashionable** nowadays.

I don't understand what the text made bold above means (I can guess though), what is the "are" referring to?

Comment: Hello, Amirreza. Please show relevant research ('[Oxford Languages](https://www.google.com/search?q=such+as+meaning&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&oq=such+as+meaning&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i67i650j0i512l8.2076078007j1j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)' gives the relevant meaning of 'such as', for instance).

Comment: Hello @EdwinAshworth, I found this sentence on a dictionary's examples section which has the same use case of "such as" as the one I mentioned, `Children do not use inflections such as are used in mature adult speech.`, this is the link: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/such, and the example was from the second section, could we consider this kind of "such as" equivalent to "as [pronoun]"? like "as they"?

Comment: Does not that sentence have exactly one plural verb and one plural noun?

Comment: ***such as...*** = ***[of the type] which** are fashionable*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Oxford Languages](https://www.google.com/search?q=such+as+meaning&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&oq=such+as+meaning&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i67i650j0i512l8.2076078007j1j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) [adjusted] gives the sense involved ([2] below):

> **such as** [phrase of such]
>
> 1. for example, like [followed by one or more noun phrases]
>
> - *wild flowers such as mountain pansy and wild thyme*
>
> 2. of a/the kind that, like [followed by an independent clause]
>
> - *a crisis such as we've been through*

So

' ... *all these 'wisdom'-filled volumes, of the type that are fashionable nowadays*.

or

' ... *all these now so fashionable 'wisdom'-filled volumes*.